# Autosubmit AJAX search form on select filter change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to make a search filter form automatically submit via AJAX when a select box is changed. The problem is using `.change` on the entire `#filter` form div. If I enter text into the `#address` input no results appear. Once I change a select value, the results will show. It works perfectly using `.submit` instead but need it to automatically send.

**JS**

```
$('#filter').change(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $('#filter');
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       var elat = place.geometry.location.lat();
       var elng = place.geometry.location.lng();

       filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elat'}).val(elat));
       filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elng'}).val(elng));

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type: 'POST', // POST
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            showCloseLocations(response);
            $('#response').html("");
        }
    });
    return false;

}).change();
```

**FORM(USING WordPress)**

```
function search_form()
{
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $widlat = $_GET['elat'];
    $widlng = $_GET['elng']; ?>

     <form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">   
     <input id="address" name="property_location" placeholder="Enter a city, country or postcode" type="text" value='<?php echo $address; ?>' required>
     <input type="hidden" id="elat" name="elat" value='<?php echo $widlat; ?>'/>
      <input type="hidden" id="elng" name="elng" value='<?php echo $widlng; ?>'/>       
       <select name="radius_miles" id="radius_km">
            <option value=1>+1 miles</option>
            <option value=2>+2 miles</option>
            <option value=5>+5 miles</option>
            <option value=30 selected>+30 miles</option>
        </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search"> 
    </form>

<?php
}
add_action('sco_search_form', 'search_form');
```

Comment: There is also a `.keyup()` function which you could make use of: https://api.jquery.com/keyup/

Comment: textboxes don't implement a "change" event. So you need to use something else to capture those as well. keyup is a reasonable choice, although you might want to stop it from auto-sending until, say, 3 characters have been entered, so you don't overload your server with searches for "a" and suchlike.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach the event handler to each visible [input](https://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) field under your form and use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event:

```
$('#filter :input:visible')
```

The full code:

```js
$('#filter :input:visible').on('input', function (e) {
    var filter = $('#filter');
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    var elat = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var elng = place.geometry.location.lng();

    filter.append($('<input>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'elat'}).val(elat));
    filter.append($('<input>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'elng'}).val(elng));

    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data: filter.serialize(),
        type: 'POST', // POST
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            showCloseLocations(response);
            $('#response').html("");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="xxx" method="POST" id="filter">
    <input id="address" name="property_location" placeholder="Enter a city, country or postcode" type="text"
           value='<?php echo $address; ?>' required>
    <input type="hidden" id="elat" name="elat" value='<?php echo $widlat; ?>'/>
    <input type="hidden" id="elng" name="elng" value='<?php echo $widlng; ?>'/>
    <select name="radius_miles" id="radius_km">
        <option value=1>+1 miles</option>
        <option value=2>+2 miles</option>
        <option value=5>+5 miles</option>
        <option value=30 selected>+30 miles</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="ek_search">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but it's now looping through the query multiple times instead of just once when changing select/inputs. See - http://i.imgur.com/dyUCphP.png

Comment: @scopeak Indeed, every time you change the select the handler function is executed. If you need to execute this only once, you can change **.on('input',** to **.one('input',**

Comment: that works too but stops any selects working after (understand why) but the response is looping the same results multiple times. So for instance, radius set to option value 1 should only output two posts. Instead it's outputting two posts 8 times extra? Hopefully diagram explains better! - http://i.imgur.com/CV0FvLp.jpg

Comment: @scopeak In order to solve this you need to decide if you need or not to post data to your server. You can do it by adding an attribute to the selected option: .attr('dontajax', 'yes/no')..... Before ajax you can test the attribute and decide. I hope this will help you

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send an request every time the input field is changed, you should use `keyup()`.

`change()` for input and textarea only update if the element loses it's focus.

Could look like this:

```js
var filter = $("#filter"),
    listener = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var elat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            var elng = place.geometry.location.lng();

            filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elat'}).val(elat));
            filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elng'}).val(elng));

        });

        $.ajax({
            url: filter.attr('action'),
            data:filter.serialize(),
            type: 'POST', // POST
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                showCloseLocations(response);
                $('#response').html("");
            }
        });
        return false;
    };


$('#address').keyup(listener);
$('#radius_km').change(listener);
```

Answer (score -2):

All events in JQuery are called with the on() method.

Here you have the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(form).on('click', function(){});

$(form).on('focusin', function(){});
```

In this case it would be like:

```
$("#filter").on('focusout', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var filter = $('#filter');
    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       var elat = place.geometry.location.lat();
       var elng = place.geometry.location.lng();

       filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elat'}).val(elat));
       filter.append( $('<input>',{type:'hidden', name:'elng'}).val(elng));

    });

    $.ajax({
        url: filter.attr('action'),
        data:filter.serialize(),
        type: 'POST', // POST
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            showCloseLocations(response);
            $('#response').html("");
        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

Comment: "All events in JQuery are called with the on() method." This statement on its own is incorrect. It's certainly _possible_ to declare all event handlers with that syntax, but not always required. There are many shortcut methods, e.g. http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/change/ being some of the more commonly-used ones. To address the specifics, "focusout" would not address the OP's requirement to search whenever the user types something. In this example they'd have to wait until focus leaves the textbox. Not very user-friendly IMHO